# VBA Display in a listbox based on two dynamic comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, listbox, userform

I would like to display the result of 2 comboboxes in a listbox but I don't know how to do it...

Here's what I've got so far :

[image: UserForm with comboboxes]
Depending on the left-hand combobox, it implies the results of the right-hand combobox.

1/ I would like to display **the package version** ($E) and **the package release** ($F) of the package name **selected** on the right-hand combobox for the project **selected** on the left combobox, ("monitoring" in this example).

2/ If I select "ALL" package name, I would like to display **$E** and **$F**.

Here is my current code :

```
Private Sub CommanButton1_Click()
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rCell As Range, Key
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = Worksheets("system-packages-installed")
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If Not Dic.exists(LCase(rCell.Value)) Then
            Dic.Add LCase(rCell.Value), Nothing
        End If
    Next rCell
    UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem "ALL"
    For Each Key In Dic
        UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem Key
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Dim rCell As Range, Key
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set ws = Worksheets("system-packages-installed")
    UserForm1.ComboBox2.Clear
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))
        If rCell.Value = ComboBox1.Value Then
            If Not Dic.exists(LCase(rCell.Offset(, 1).Value)) Then
                Dic.Add LCase(rCell.Offset(, 1).Value), Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell
    UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem "ALL"
    For Each Key In Dic
        UserForm1.ComboBox2.AddItem Key
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Click()
    'This is a test'
    With UserForm1.ListBox1
        .ColumnCount = 27
        .ColumnWidths = "50"
        .RowSource = "'system-packages-installed'!E:E"
    End With
End Sub
```

If you have any question, do not hesitate to ask me.

Thanks in advance.

Edit :

Here is the table :

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-0pky">System_id<br></th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">Machine</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">package_name</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">package_epoch</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">package_version</th>
    <th class="tg-0pky">package_release</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">acl</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2.2.51</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">14.el7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">alsa-lib</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1.1.6</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2.el7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">apg</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2.3.0b</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">24.el7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">apr</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1.4.8</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3.el7_4.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">apr-util</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1.5.2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">6.el7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">at</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">3.1.13</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">24.el7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0pky">1000010000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">monitoring</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">audit</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">2.8.4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">4.el7</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please dont add data as images, add them as text. You can google for "markdown table" and make a table from it as well.

Comment: Also, what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: I don't really understand why you're saying "dont add data as images"...
My current code is correct. But I don't really know how to display values depending on my two comboboxes...

Comment: He's saying you show a picture of your data in an Excel sheet. But if anyone wants to recreate your situation and test their answer, they'd have to type (rather than copy and paste) all of that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My rule is never use `RowSource`. Generally, if you can put the information in an array, then you can assign that array to the `Lisbtobx.List` property. The other method is to add a new item with `AddItem` and then fill out the rest of the columns with the `List()` property.  Below is an example. I made some minor changes to your existing code and the ComboBox2_Change code I think is what you're interested in.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Dim rCell As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dc.Add "ALL", "ALL"

    Set ws = Worksheets("system-packages-installed")
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If rCell.Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
            If Not dc.exists(LCase(rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)) Then
                dc.Add LCase(rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value), LCase(rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value)
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell

    Me.ComboBox2.List = dc.Items

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("system-packages-installed")
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If LCase(rCell.Value) = LCase(Me.ComboBox1.Value) Or Me.ComboBox1.Value = "ALL" Then
            If LCase(rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value) = LCase(Me.ComboBox2.Value) Or Me.ComboBox2.Value = "ALL" Then
                With Me.ListBox1
                    .AddItem rCell.Value 'column 1
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value 'column 2
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 2) = rCell.Offset(0, 3).Value 'column 3
                    .List(.ListCount - 1, 3) = rCell.Offset(0, 4).Value 'column 4
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rCell As Range

    Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dc = New Scripting.Dictionary
    dc.Add "ALL", "ALL"

    Set ws = Worksheets("system-packages-installed")
    Me.ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("B2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)).Cells
        If Not dc.exists(LCase(rCell.Value)) Then
            dc.Add LCase(rCell.Value), LCase(rCell.Value)
        End If
    Next rCell

    Me.ComboBox1.List = dc.Items

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I don't know why, but the code you've done doesn't work. It seems that the problem is during the sub "UserForm1_Initialize" but I don't find it for the moment.

Comment: I've added a part of my table on the main question. I don't find where is the problem...

Comment: @AChichi - [1] there's no `UserForm1_Initialize` event but only a `UserForm_Initialize` event in the form's code; it's worth mentioning that referencing controls like `UserForm1.ComboBox2` address the form's default instance, avoid that - use only the control's name or the `Me.` qualifier (e.g. `Me.ComboBox2`) instead as Dick demonstrated to address the actual current instance. [2.] Did you assign the  `.ColumnCount` property (e.g. to 4) or the `.ColumnWidths` property for *eac* column (e.g. to `"50;50;50;50"`)? BTW  [See](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

Comment: @AChichi You commented *"I don't find where is the problem"* - so **what** exactly is your problem, what "doesn't work"?

Comment: @T.M. I had the error _User-defined type not defined_, I changed this `Dim dc As Scripting.Dictionary` to this `Dim dc As Object` and `Set dc = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`. Now the listbox is working. But it only display the column "_Machine_" and not the other. I'll check why

Comment: @T.M. After adding `.ColumnCount = 4` as you told me, it's working well. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @AChichi - glad you got Dick's absolutely correct solution working. FYI Using a dictionary by so called *early binding* you need to add a reference via VBA Editor ~> Tools ~> References ~> Add **Microsoft Scripting Runtime** with some advantages in speed and IntelliSense comfort - check the differences to *late binding* by your own :-)